# Magento 2: Disable custom product attribute editing?

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, product-attribute

[image: Blacklisted Toggle]

I have a custom product attribute called `blacklisted`, which indicates if a product is currently blacklisted. This is controlled by a cronjob and **shouldn't be edited** by an admin. It however **should be visible** to an admin on the product edit page.

Maybe there is a way to implement a new `frontend_input` type?

Any tips on how I can achieve this?